# connect.sid reset when browser shutdown and turned back on

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session-cookies

Everything seems to be working fine when I implemented my session store except for the fact that when I close my browser and turn it back on the connect.sid or the session id has been changed to a new one, forcing my login system to automatically assume that the user is logged out. How can I make sure that even if I close my browser the connect.sid stays the same in the browser so when I access my website the user is automatically logged in?

```
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
        collection: 'MongoStore',
        autoRemove: 'native',
        ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 14 days
    }),
        secret: 'secret',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        maxAge: null
}))
```

Dependencies for session:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo/es5')(session);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the cookie parser secret to match the session secret I was able to achieve what I wanted.

```
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
```